# Why citation number is changed in beamer?

Tags: beamer, citing

My presentation has slides 1-10. I use same reference in slide 3 and slide 5. Both times the full citation appears differently. Also the number also changes. Why is this the case. This doesnt happen when latex is used for making documents like article or papers?

Comment: Without a minimal example of code is impossible to understand what is happening. Reference to you is a bibliography one? Or do you mean equation numbers? Each slide is a page in the output pdf and a lot of slides is created when you do a `frame` with overlays.